# How can I change lowercases to '-' in the even and odd lines using sed piping?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line

I want to convert the lowercase sequences (a,t,c,g) into '-' using the Unix command. But it's not saving the file in place. Rather it's showing errors and removing '-i' outputs in the terminal but doesn't change anything in the file. However, it outputs the desired result for the following code in the terminal but doesn't change the file. You can see that after header information, there are sequence pairs. I just want to change the sequence pairs, keeping header info unchanged. The file's nature is:

```
0 chr1 11680 11871 chr6 28206109 28206336 - 4581
ctggagattctta-ttagtgatttgggctggggcc-tggccatgtgtattttttta-aatttccactgatgattttgctgcatggccggtgttgagaatgactgCG-CAAATTTGCCGGATTTCCTTTGCTGTTCCTGCATGTAGTTTAAACGAGATTGCCAGCACCGGGTATCATTCAC----------------------------------------------CATTTTTCTTTTCGTT
-TAGGGAGTCTTAGTCAAAGGTTTGGACCAAGTCCCTGGCCATGCAGATCTTTGTAGAATCTCCACTCGTGACTTTCCTGCATAACCAGAGTTGAGCATCTTTGAGTCAAGTGTGCCA-ACTTTCTTTGCTGTT-------------TAAATAAGGATGCCAACACCGCATGTCATTAACAGTCTCGTAGGTTGATTGATTTGTTGGCTGGCTCAAAAATGAGAGTTATTTTTCATTTTGTT

1 chr1 11872 12139 chr6 28206484 28206708 - 4257
AACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT
AGTTTTCTGTCTGCTAATT-TGCCACCAGTCATTTCCTATTACGTGTGTCTGCTGCCTCCTAGCCCAGGCT-----TGCCCTTCCTCCC--TCTTCTGAGGTGTCATAGGGTCGTGAC--------------------TTACCTGGTTTGGGGGAGTAGTTGG---------------AAGCTGAGTGA-GTGGTGGGGTTTTCTTATGCTAAAGACCTGCGTCCAGTATAGGAAGAGCCATGTGCCTCCACTCTGGCCCTTGTGGTCT

2 chr1 12177 12259 chr17 66149263 66149338 + 3811
GATTGGAGGAAAGATGAGTGAGAGCATCAACTTCTCTCACAACCTAGGCCAGTAAGTAGTGCTTGTGCTCATCTCCTTGGCTG
GGTTGGAGGGAAGATGAGTGAAGGGATCAATTTCTCTGATGACCTGGGCCGGTAGG-------TGTGGTGTCCTCTTTGTCTG
```

Desired Output:

```
0 chr1 11680 11871 chr6 28206109 28206336 - 4581
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CG-CAAATTTGCCGGATTTCCTTTGCTGTTCCTGCATGTAGTTTAAACGAGATTGCCAGCACCGGGTATCATTCAC----------------------------------------------CATTTTTCTTTTCGTT
-TAGGGAGTCTTAGTCAAAGGTTTGGACCAAGTCCCTGGCCATGCAGATCTTTGTAGAATCTCCACTCGTGACTTTCCTGCATAACCAGAGTTGAGCATCTTTGAGTCAAGTGTGCCA-ACTTTCTTTGCTGTT-------------TAAATAAGGATGCCAACACCGCATGTCATTAACAGTCTCGTAGGTTGATTGATTTGTTGGCTGGCTCAAAAATGAGAGTTATTTTTCATTTTGTT

1 chr1 11872 12139 chr6 28206484 28206708 - 4257
AACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT
AGTTTTCTGTCTGCTAATT-TGCCACCAGTCATTTCCTATTACGTGTGTCTGCTGCCTCCTAGCCCAGGCT-----TGCCCTTCCTCCC--TCTTCTGAGGTGTCATAGGGTCGTGAC--------------------TTACCTGGTTTGGGGGAGTAGTTGG---------------AAGCTGAGTGA-GTGGTGGGGTTTTCTTATGCTAAAGACCTGCGTCCAGTATAGGAAGAGCCATGTGCCTCCACTCTGGCCCTTGTGGTCT

2 chr1 12177 12259 chr17 66149263 66149338 + 3811
GATTGGAGGAAAGATGAGTGAGAGCATCAACTTCTCTCACAACCTAGGCCAGTAAGTAGTGCTTGTGCTCATCTCCTTGGCTG
GGTTGGAGGGAAGATGAGTGAAGGGATCAATTTCTCTGATGACCTGGGCCGGTAGG-------TGTGGTGTCCTCTTTGTCTG
```

```
#for even lines
sed -n 2~2p h.txt| sed 's/a/-/g' | sed 's/t/-/g' | sed 's/c/-/g' | sed 's/g/-/g' 
#for odd lines
sed -n 1~2p h.txt| sed -n 2~2p | sed 's/a/-/g'| sed 's/t/-/g' | sed 's/c/-/g' | sed 's/g/-/g'
```

Comment: Are these fasta sequences? Does the header actually start with a `>` in the real file?

Comment: Of course it's not editing in place. It's writing to _stdout_, which you need to capture to a temporary file. On successful completion you then overwrite the original file with the new one. That's how "in place editing" actually works - it's just that the process is hidden from you

Comment: @terdon Kind of same. These are AXT files obtained from UCSC. No, header doesn't start with any special character.

Comment: @roaima Yes, absolutely correct. It contains 11 lines.

Comment: How do you identify a header? And what's the difference in the expected output between even and odd lines?

Comment: @aviro I got the expected outputs but I need to make changes to the same file. But for now, it's just outputting in the terminal.

Comment: "it's showing errors" -- _what_ errors? Also, what's the point about even and odd lines? You want to change lowercase characters to `-` on both of them? So, on all lines? Do you also want to separate the even and odd lines from each other? Actually, can you just [edit] the question to show what the output corresponding to the input file there should look like?

Comment: The thing is that I don't understand what the expected output should be. Basically your problem is that you're running multiple `sed` commands in pipes, and in order to make the changes in place, you need to convert those multiple commands to a single `sed` command with a `-i` flag, but to help you reach this result I want to understand what the expected output should be.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. I have edited the post with desired outputs.

Comment: I still don't understand what's the difference between even and odd line numbers, and how do you distinguish the headers (that are not supposed to change).

Comment: @aviro The answer is already within my code. By manipulating the line number, you can tell Unix not to change header info. But I just need to change my original file rather than printing on the terminal.

Comment: Please make that your question. It doesn't actually say in your question that this is what you want help with. I'd have contributed an answer immediately if it had been clear this is what you wanted

Comment: Your output has `ctgg...` on the second line turned into `----...`, ok. But then it has `cTAG...` on the third line turned into `-TAG...`. That is, the change is made on both an odd and an even line. Which means that the even/odd distinction is questionable at best. You're asking strangers to help you, you'd make it easier for them if you just told what you actually wanted, instead of muddying it up with specifications that aren't actually relevant (or even correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `perl` instead since that has the `$.` special variable which holds the current line number. So if `$.` modulo 2 is 0 (`if $. % 2 == 0`), then we change all occurrences of `a`, `t`, `c` or `g` to `-`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/[actg]/-/g if $. % 2 == 0' file 
0 chr1 11680 11871 chr6 28206109 28206336 - 4581
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CG-CAAATTTGCCGGATTTCCTTTGCTGTTCCTGCATGTAGTTTAAACGAGATTGCCAGCACCGGGTATCATTCAC----------------------------------------------CATTTTTCTTTTCGTT
cTAGGGAGTCTTAGTCAAAGGTTTGGACCAAGTCCCTGGCCATGCAGATCTTTGTAGAATCTCCACTCGTGACTTTCCTGCATAACCAGAGTTGAGCATCTTTGAGTCAAGTGTGCCA-ACTTTCTTTGCTGTT-------------TAAATAAGGATGCCAACACCGCATGTCATTAACAGTCTCGTAGGTTGATTGATTTGTTGGCTGGCTCAAAAATGAGAGTTATTTTTCATTTTGTT

1 chr1 11872 12139 chr6 28206484 28206708 - 4257
AACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT
AGTTTTCTGTCTGCTAATT-TGCCACCAGTCATTTCCTATTACGTGTGTCTGCTGCCTCCTAGCCCAGGCT-----TGCCCTTCCTCCC--TCTTCTGAGGTGTCATAGGGTCGTGAC--------------------TTACCTGGTTTGGGGGAGTAGTTGG---------------AAGCTGAGTGA-GTGGTGGGGTTTTCTTATGCTAAAGACCTGCGTCCAGTATAGGAAGAGCCATGTGCCTCCACTCTGGCCCTTGTGGTCT

2 chr1 12177 12259 chr17 66149263 66149338 + 3811
GATTGGAGGAAAGATGAGTGAGAGCATCAACTTCTCTCACAACCTAGGCCAGTAAGTAGTGCTTGTGCTCATCTCCTTGGCTG
GGTTGGAGGGAAGATGAGTGAAGGGATCAATTTCTCTGATGACCTGGGCCGGTAGG-------TGTGGTGTCCTCTTTGTCTG
```

To make the change in the original file, just use `-i`:

```
perl -i -pe 's/[actg]/-/g if $. % 2 == 0' file
```

---

However, I don't think you actually want only the even lines. You seem to want to change lower case residues to dashes on the sequence lines. If so, you can focus on lines that don't contain any spaces and make the change there:

```
$ perl -pe 's/[actg]/-/g if !/ /' file
0 chr1 11680 11871 chr6 28206109 28206336 - 4581
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CG-CAAATTTGCCGGATTTCCTTTGCTGTTCCTGCATGTAGTTTAAACGAGATTGCCAGCACCGGGTATCATTCAC----------------------------------------------CATTTTTCTTTTCGTT
-TAGGGAGTCTTAGTCAAAGGTTTGGACCAAGTCCCTGGCCATGCAGATCTTTGTAGAATCTCCACTCGTGACTTTCCTGCATAACCAGAGTTGAGCATCTTTGAGTCAAGTGTGCCA-ACTTTCTTTGCTGTT-------------TAAATAAGGATGCCAACACCGCATGTCATTAACAGTCTCGTAGGTTGATTGATTTGTTGGCTGGCTCAAAAATGAGAGTTATTTTTCATTTTGTT

1 chr1 11872 12139 chr6 28206484 28206708 - 4257
AACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT
AGTTTTCTGTCTGCTAATT-TGCCACCAGTCATTTCCTATTACGTGTGTCTGCTGCCTCCTAGCCCAGGCT-----TGCCCTTCCTCCC--TCTTCTGAGGTGTCATAGGGTCGTGAC--------------------TTACCTGGTTTGGGGGAGTAGTTGG---------------AAGCTGAGTGA-GTGGTGGGGTTTTCTTATGCTAAAGACCTGCGTCCAGTATAGGAAGAGCCATGTGCCTCCACTCTGGCCCTTGTGGTCT

2 chr1 12177 12259 chr17 66149263 66149338 + 3811
GATTGGAGGAAAGATGAGTGAGAGCATCAACTTCTCTCACAACCTAGGCCAGTAAGTAGTGCTTGTGCTCATCTCCTTGGCTG
GGTTGGAGGGAAGATGAGTGAAGGGATCAATTTCTCTGATGACCTGGGCCGGTAGG-------TGTGGTGTCCTCTTTGTCTG
```

Once again, to modify the original file instead of printing to standard output, use `-i`:

```
perl -i -pe 's/[actg]/-/g if !/ /' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding how that even / odd thing is to be interpreted, I came up with

```
sed '/[^acgtACGT-]/!s/[acgt]/-/g' file
```

Lines that have any character other than a,c,g,t,A,C,G,T, or "-", will be printed unaltered. Any resifual line will have its lower case characters replaced with "-"
Redirect to a temporary file, and then overwrite the original.

Comment: Or just use `-i` flag for in-place replacement in `sed`...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can a,t,c,g to - in one line using:

```
sed -i 's/[atcg]/-/g' FILE
```

Of course that would change those on all the lines. You you need to choose where to apply those to. It's usually better to do that using some pattern matching, but if you're insisting on doing this according to line numbers, then first you need to understand what the following command you wrote does:

```
sed -n 1~2p h.txt| sed -n 2~2p ...
```

This actually prints every 4th step starting from the third number, and could be replaced by: `3~4`.

So to combine those:

```
sed -i '2~2s/[atcg]/-/g; 3~4s/[atcg]/-/g' FILE
```

By the way, `2~2` only works in this case because every 4th line is empty. In that case, you could actually replace it with `2~4`, without trying to manipulate the empty lines.

But anyway, what most people would do would be to distinguish "header" and "non headers" line by pattern matching. For instance, assuming all of your header line (and **only** header lines) begin with a digit, you could ignore them by:

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]/! s/[atcg]/-/g' FILE
```